# Frame doesn't change background color

Tags: java

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("New Frame");
    frame.setSize(1000,750);
    frame.add(new myComponent());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.pink);
```

When I run this, the background in the frame still appears as white and not pink. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
```

Comment: You can't do exactly what you're trying to do. Read the first answer in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11268357/why-wont-my-background-color-display-in-jframe). [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) might be a good place to continue to.